# What is the exact difference between pseudo mode and stand alone mode in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

What is the exact difference between pseudo mode and stand alone mode in hadoop?

How can we get to know that when working on our own laptop / desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences are the one described in the product documentation:

> [Standalone Operation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Standalone_Operation): By default, Hadoop is configured to run in a non-distributed mode, as a single Java process. This is useful for debugging.
>
> [Pseudo-Distributed Operation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation): Hadoop can also be run on a single-node in a pseudo-distributed mode where each Hadoop daemon runs in a separate Java process.

Unless you want to debug Hadoop code, you should always run in pseudo-distributed.